# mysql trigger with insert and update after insert on table

Tags: mysql

```
create table Test1
(
WRO varchar(10),
Test_No varchar(10),
TestDate datetime
);

insert into Test1(WRO,TestDate) values('T0001',now());

create table Test2
(
WRO varchar(10),
Test_No varchar(10),
Test2Date datetime,
TestAmount varchar(10)
);
```

I have to update and Insert on Test1 Test_No after insert on Test2 table Test_No both have common field WRO.

```
insert into Test2 values('DSK','400',now(),3000);
insert into Test2 values('T0001','200',now(),3000);
```

if wro no of test2 table not match with test1 then insert query should be fired in test1 table

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood you properly.

The following trigger on `Test2` table will insert new row into `Test1` table if `WRO` field of new row doesn't exist in `Test1`.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Test2`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if not exists (select 1 from Test1 where WRO = new.WRO) then
         insert into Test1 (WRO, Test_No) values (new.WRO, new.Test_No);
    end if;   
 END
```